# Cannot convert double to boolean

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

Apologies if this is confusing, I'm still new to coding. I'm trying to prompt the user for a number and display if the number entered is or is not in the array. Can't really seem to find an answer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Arrays3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] don = { 2.1, 3.2, 4.5, 6.0, 4.5, 1.5, 6.0, 7.0, 6.0, 9.0 };
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        double num = kbd.nextDouble();
        if (num = don.length) {
            System.out.println("The number you entered is in the Array");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The number you entered is not in the Array");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are searching for the input value inside your data array, you may want to traverse the array and check if the input matches with any value inside the array.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] don = { 2.1, 3.2, 4.5, 6.0, 4.5, 1.5, 6.0, 7.0, 6.0, 9.0 };
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    double num = kbd.nextDouble();
    boolean isFound = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < don.length; i++) {
        if (num == don[i]) {
            isFound = true;
        }
    }

    if (isFound) {
        System.out.println("The number you entered is in the Array");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The number you entered is not in the Array");
    }
}
```

There are few ways to check if the element exists in the array

- Using a for-loop
- Java 8 Stream API
- Arrays.asList().contains()

Answer (score 0):

You've used

```java
if (num = don.length) {
```

where you should have used

```java
if (num == don.length) {
```

In the first case, you are assigning `don.length` to `num`, returning the newly assigned value.

Additionally, your code does not check whether the read number is in your array. To check for this, you could use something like:

```java
boolean found = false;
for(int i = 0; i < don.length; i++) {
    if(num == don[i]) {
        found = true;
        break; // Stop the loop as a match has already been found.
    }
}
if(found) {
    System.out.println("The number you entered is in the Array");
} else {
    System.out.println("The number you entered is not in the Array");
}
```

Comment: While this answer is somewhat true, it does not answer the stated question on how to test if the input, being a double, is in the array or not

Comment: @bajro You are right, I've adjusted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of checking if your input, in this case `num`, is present in the given array `don` or not:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] don = { 2.1, 3.2, 4.5, 6.0, 4.5, 1.5, 6.0, 7.0, 6.0, 9.0 };
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    double num = kbd.nextDouble();
    boolean existsInArray = Arrays.stream(don).anyMatch(arrayNum -> arrayNum == num);

    if (existsInArray) {
      System.out.println("The number you entered is in the Array");
    } else {
      System.out.println("The number you entered is not in the Array");
    }
  }
}
```

The `existsInArray` variable is using the Java 8 Stream API, and in particular the `anyMatch()` method, to check if the given input (called `num` here), is contained in the array `don`. If so, `existsInArray` is `true` else `false`.